secpol.msc - An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist
I'm trying to figure out why the "Local Security Policy" service "secpol.msc" doesn't start.
The message is "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist".
"gpedit.msc", which has the same settings in the subfolder, works without errors.

I have researched on the internet and tried the following:
1.
sfc /scannow




kill explorer

Is there a way to trace back the cause of the error? Like a logfile or the possibility to restore
secpol.msc environment without affecting other parts of windows?
